# Modifying JSON keys with Groovy

Tags: arrays, json, groovy

I have JSON output coming from the server like the following that I'm trying to clean up the key values to reduce their length and remove their spaces. I'm able to fix the initial key of an array using the put/remove, but can't seem to do the same with the key values of the array.

```
{
"Customer Information": [
     {"Data Table - F0102 [Contacts - Emails]": [{
     "name":"xxxxx",
     "email":"xxxxx"
     }]},
     {"Data Table - F3392 [Contacts - Phone Numbers]":[{
     "phone_desc":"xxxxx",
     "phone_number":"xxxxx"
     }]}
],
"address":"xxxxx",
"city":"xxxxx",
"state":"xxxxx",
"zip":"xxxxx"
}
```

I'm using the following code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder;

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def object = jsonSlurper.parseText'''{JSON FROM ABOVE}'''

// this first line works, and updates to customer_info
object.put("customer_info", object.remove("Customer Information"));

// this line seems to be ignored
object.put("email_info", object.remove("Data Table - F0102 [Contacts - Emails]"));

def jsonOut = new JsonBuilder(object).toPrettyString();
return jsonOut;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You variable named `object` is a bit hurting my eyes :-) You might want to give it a more descriptive name. As well, you can drop the `;` in groovy code.

Anyway, 'object' is a `Map<String, Object>` describing your json from its root. So, `object."Customer Information"` exists but `object."Data Table - F0102 [Contacts - Emails]"` does not. `object."Customer Information"[0]."Data Table - F0102 [Contacts - Emails]"` does.

So you can replace your line `object.put("email_info", object.remove("Data Table - F0102 [Contacts - Emails]"))` by `object.customer_info[0].put("email_info", object.customer_info[0].remove('Data Table - F0102 [Contacts - Emails]'))`. But as `object."Customer Information"` is a list, it might be safer to use a loop, especially if the number of elements in it can differ depending on the customer.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense :). Thanks so much.. that was exactly what I needed! First time using groovy with json here.